# Searching in a text file using command prompt

Tags: command-prompt

I am running this command on the command prompt

```
findstr "Updater"  * > a.txt
```

In my text file is like this

> Updater.UpdateActivitiesInApp Errors located:ActualStartDate: Actual
>   Start cannot be greater than Actual Finish for Activity 1234.
>   Updater.UpsertUDFValues Error while trying to validate session using
>   cookie authentication: Invalid session. Please login again.

Result I'm getting is:-

> log.log:Updater.UpdateActivitiesInApp  log.log:Updater.UpsertUDFValues
>   Error while trying to validate session using cookie authentication:
>   Invalid session. Please login again.

In first line Errors located is not printed. What is wrong here

Comment: Also if i can give number of character to be return after finding the matching string will be helpful.

Comment: Please provide some actual log text to download so we can test a batch file and also show what you want as the output of the search.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your data to show clearly what your source and results are. You may have to use the help on markdown to find appropriate formatting.

In all probabiity, the fault is occurring because you are looking in `All files` and `findstr` may be closing the output after each.

It probably doesn't help that you are creating `a.txt` simultaneously in the same directory.

Try

```
findstr "Updater"  * >> "%temp%\a.txt"
```

where `a.txt` will be created in your `temp` directory.

- I have no idea where your `temp` directory is; try `echo %temp%` from
  the prompt for clues
- `%temp%` is just a suggestion; any directory other than the current should suffice.
- Since `>>` appends to any existing file, deleting `a.txt` beforehand may be of benefit.

Comment: first two line (in first highlighted text)is single line in my source text file. But in my result file (second highlighted portion) i am not getting full line as you see second log.log in result is coming in first line.